# Azure Mobile SDK to register Xamarin clients with Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Short version: Is there an end-to-end sample that shows how to register a Xamarin client with Azure Notification Hub using their Mobile SDK and the new Installation Model?

Long version:

The docs on Azure mention the support to [register client devices using the Installation Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview#integration-with-app-service-mobile-apps).

I'm using Xamarin Forms and this looks like the way to go, but I don't see any related code in Microsoft's Mobile Client Packages. The closest thing I found was that article that recommends [using a Xamarin "Google Cloud Messaging Client" component for registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-and-run-the-android-project-optional), but that seems to be a 3rd party library that seems to have been around for years and hasn't been touched in months.

---

Edit: I discovered way too many outdated, broken or conflicting tutorials on both the Microsoft and Xamarin sites, so [I listed them and asked for guidance on the Xamarin Forms forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85131/which-library-to-use-with-notification-hubs-and-what-tutorial-to-follow). I'll keep this thread synced.

Comment: You're correct, unfortunately there's not much documentation on installations at the moment. The product team is working on it. And new SDK versions are in the works. If you have any specific questions, please update your post and I'll try to answer to the best of my knowledge. If you're asking in general, then it looks like you've already found pretty much everything you'd need.

Comment: Thanks, Nikita. I appears that at the moment, Xamarin Forms doesn't even support Firebase cloud messaging (FCM), which means I'll just have to suck it up. I'll update the thread if there's any news - there hasn't been any feedback on the Xamarin Forum.